# Can't able to update my node package manager npm

Tags: reactjs, node.js, windows, npm, terminal

I tried to update my node package manager using `npm install -g npm` this command in my windows system. But it sounds like error I can't able to update.
It sounds like

```
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Toggle-Theme> npm install -g npm
npm WARN cli npm v10.0.0 does not support Node.js v18.14.2. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.3.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.3.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"10.0.0","node":"v18.14.2"}
```

I expecting to update my node package manager and node version to latest version of node globally

Comment: What's unclear from the message? npm 10 requires Node ^18.17, you have 18.14.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Upgrade your installation of node to `^18.17.0` or `>=20.5.0` and then try to upgrade your install of npm.

---

**Long Answer:**

npm error messages are not always the clearest, but in this case it's pretty clear. I'll break this error message down for you to help you better understand why you can't install an updated version of npm.

This warning is in plain text and pretty much spells out the entire issue and how to fix it:

```
npm WARN cli npm v10.0.0 does not support Node.js v18.14.2. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

You are attempting to upgrade npm to a version which is unsupported for the  version of node you have installed (v18.14.2).  In order to update, you need to first upgrade your version of node to ^18.17.0 or >=20.5.0.  If you're not familiar with semantic versioning and `^` & `>=` (among others) notation, there are many good articles out there that explain it well.

---

```
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
```

This is the actual error code being thrown.

---

```
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.3.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.3.0
```

These lines all say that what you're trying to upgrade to is not compatible with your currently installed engine (node) version.

---

```
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
```

> `notsup` means `not supported`.

This tells you what the minimum required versions are to do this upgrade.

---

```
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"10.0.0","node":"v18.14.2"}
```

And this line tells you what you currently have installed.

---

Hope this little breakdown helps you out!